# If $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear, is f always one-to-one?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here's what I thought would be a pretty self-explanatory question, but I find myself second-guessing my reasonings. I thought about a counter-example; the constant function, but if someone could provide a definitive answer, it would help me sleep better!

I was given these definitions of linear, for context:

A function $f : \mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is called linear if, for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,

1. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
2. $\alpha f(x)= f(\alpha x)$

And additionally,

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a given function. Then the following are equivalent.

1. f is linear
2. There is an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ such that, $f(X) = AX$ for all $X \in \mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: $f=0$ is a  counter-example.

Comment: It will never be $1$-$1$ if $n \gt m$.  Prove that $f$ is $1$-$1$ if and only if $f(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=0$.

Comment: @RobertShore what about $f\big((x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\big) = (x_1-x_2,0,0,\ldots)$ which will not be one-to-one if $n>1$?

Comment: @Henry What about it?  I said that $n \gt m \Rightarrow f$ is not $1$-$1$.  I didn't say that $n \leq m \Rightarrow f$ is $1$-$1$.  I gave a necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to be $1$-$1$.  Note than in your example, $f((1, 1, 0, \ldots, 0))=(0, \ldots 0)$.